# Volume of Revolution...

Tags: calculus, volume

I'm studying for a test and am stuck on one volume problem.

The figure is rotated about the x-axis and is bounded by
$$
y=x^2, y=\frac{(3-x)}{2},y=0. 
$$

I thought the solution would be:
$$
\pi\int_{0}^{1}(\frac{3-x}{2})^{2}-(x^{2})^{2}dx
$$
However, the key is indicating that this is wrong. Any insights as to where I may have gone wrong would be appreciated.

Additional question: Is the area integrated between the two curves and the x-axis then rotated about the x-axis? Or is the area integrated between the two curves and the y axis then rotated about the x-axis? Which area am I "shading?" Unsure if that made sense but I believe that is where I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the problem

Answer (score 1):

hints

$f(x)= x^2.$

$g(x) = (3-x)/2.$

where does:

- $f(x)$ hit the $x$-axis?
- $g(x)$ hit the $x$-axis?
- $f(x)$ hit $g(x)$?

given a height $f(x)$, from $a$ to $b$, what is the formula for the volume of revolution generated by $f(x)$?

**Addendum**
Per OP's comment/question:

The stated problem actually involves a region that has one *height* for $x \leq 1$ and a different *height* for $x \geq 1.$  This is how you should be interpreting the instructions:

The figure is rotated about the x-axis and is bounded by
$$
y=x^2, y=\frac{(3-x)}{2},y=0. 
$$

This means that the volume of revolution is **completely solid**, with no (inner gap).  This means that the cross-sectional area is $\pi\times R^2$, where $R$ is either equal to $f(x)$ or $g(x)$, depending on whether $x \leq 1$ or $x \geq 1$.

Contrast that with a different problem:

Let $s(x) = 2.$

Let $t(x) = 1.$

Consider the region bounded by $x=0$, $x=3$, $s(x)$ and $t(x)$.

If you were considering the volume of revolution for this region rotated about the $x$-axis, you would realize that the 3 dimensional solid formed has a **hole** in it, like a hollow cylinder.

Here, the formula for the cross-sectional area would be $\pi \times (R^2 - r^2)$, where $R$ is the outer radius of $s(x)$ and $r$ is the inner radius of $t(x)$.

Comment: So I understand this would then be: $$ \pi\int_{0}^{1}(x^2)^2dx+\pi\int_{1}^{3}(\frac{3-x}{2})^2dx $$ I'm a bit confused as to why we are integrating the area "below" the curve and not "between" the curves if that makes sense. Why would it not simply be: $$ \pi\int_{a}^{b}(g(x))^2-(f(x))^2dx $$

Comment: @redfish see the addendum to my answer.